# How to build Curved stock chart with AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

There is a possibility to create **Curve time series** plot with `AmCharts` as detailed in https://www.amcharts.com/demos/smoothed-line-chart/

However I am hoping there should be similar way to make **Curved chart for Stock-charts** as well. However I failed to find any such implementation over internet.

Any pointer *how to create a Curved plot for Stock-chart* will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your link points to an empty codepen. Save your codepen and provide an updated link.

Comment: Hi xorspark, Link is corrected now

Comment: v4 doesn't have a stock chart yet. You'll have to use v3. You can set the stockGraph type to [`smoothedLine`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#type) and use [`negativeBase`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#negativeBase) and [`negativeLineColor`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#negativeLineColor) for changing the color at certain thresholds. I recommend using one of the v3 stock demos like [this one](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/multiple-data-sets-v3/) to start from.